# How can I make a fluid width header with text-overflow ellipsis without wrapping?

Tags: html, css

I need a header and button on the same line, using ellipses if necessary.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epyFT/1/

I'd like output to look like this:

```
_________________________________________________________
|                                                       |
| Header goes here [button]                             |
|                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Or

```
_________________________________________________________
|                                                       |
| Super, super, super, super long header... [button]    |
|                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Or with a smaller window:

```
____________________________
|                          |
| Header goes... [button]  |
|                          |
----------------------------
```

The button should never float to the next line.  How can I do this?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>This is the header that should never wrap and elipse if it doesn't fit</h2>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width:100%;
}
h2 {
    display:inline;
    min-width:200px;
    overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; word-break: break-all; word-wrap: break-word;
}
button {
    width:100px;
}
```

---

**Bonus**

Extra credit for getting a second (fixed width) button in there to pull right.

```
_________________________________________________________
|                                                       |
| Header goes here [button1]                  [button2] |
|                                                       |
|                                                       |
| Super, super, super, super long... [button] [button2] |
|                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Do you have any target browser requirements?

Comment: Unfortunately, `text-overflow:ellipsis;` only works with block containers. 
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#text-overflow

Comment: @Dan, the usual modern ones — Chrome, Safari, IE 8, Firefox, etc.

Comment: @SonuJoshi, Can I emulate a block container?  I tried inline-block and table-cell for the h2.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Dan solved it already. I was doing something like that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe something like this helps? http://jsfiddle.net/epyFT/3/

I'm not sure how to make the button align to the no-wrapped width of the container, and am only using percentage widths for the cells.

New code:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.container>div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.cell1 {}

.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.cell2 {
  width: 60%;
}

h2 {
  display: inline;
  min-width: 200px;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell1">
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2>This is the header that should never wrap and elipse if it doesn't fit</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell2">
    <button>Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!  I didn't need the extra cell1 wrap, but it worked flawlessly!  I was even able to squeeze in an extra static width div on the right.  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epyFT/7/  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, if the H2 is wrapped, it could have right-margin or padding with relative positioning, and the button could be absolute positioned into that padding area.

Comment: But be careful about relative/absolute positioning with table-cell.. it gets weird across the browsers.

Comment: Little more help.  Turns out the button doesn't float to the left when the header is smaller.  See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epyFT/8/  Any idea how to make the button stick closer to the header (pull left when there's room).

Comment: Check my new answer below.. Consider changing accepted answer? =)

Comment: Still struggling to make it all come together in real life, but thanks for your help Dan.  Added a new question to make things a little clearer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126585/how-can-i-have-a-fluid-width-header-inside-a-fluid-width-container-with-a-fixed

Answer (score 7):

I think I found you a better solution: http://jsfiddle.net/epyFT/9/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>This is a very long heading that should wrap with ellipsis when too long, but have a button to it's right.</h2>
    <button>Hello.</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <h2>This is short.</h2>
    <button>Sup</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
   max-width:100%;
   position: relative;
}
h2 {  
    padding-right: 200px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    word-break: break-all; 
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    right: 95px;
    top: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
}
.oneline {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="oneline">This is the header that should never wrap and elipse if it doesn't fit</h2>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
     <h2 class="oneline">Header</h2>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gu7qf/2/)

To align the buttons at the right side, add `width: 80%;` to `.oneline`.

Comment: I can't get this one to work.  The container doesn't really fill 100% width.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRkmu/

Comment: @Ryan When I add `border: 1px solid red;` to `.container` it extends up to the right edge. What do you want to achieve? Should the buttons be flushed right? I'm using FF 20, btw.

Comment: I see what you mean about the 100% width. But this only works if you have a fixed width header. I want the header to be fluid (i.e. fit as much possible). Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zRkmu/3/

Comment: @Ryan You can move the `max-width` to `wrapper`, which allows to use a percentage width. Maybe this is more what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I took Dan's great answer (which was only compatible with Webkit browsers), and made it compatible with Firefox and Internet Explorer 8+.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hammerbrostime/9t5bX/1/

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  padding-right: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-break: break-all;
  /* word-wrap: break-word;  taken out, caused issues in IE */
  max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
  /* FF hack */
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  right: 95px;
  top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>This is a very long heading that should wrap with ellipsis when too long, but have a button to it's right.</h2>
  <button>Hello.</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h2>This is short.</h2>
  <button>Sup</button>
</div>
```